# Why MVC does autoupdate of EF Model Classes?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model, entity

I generated Entity Model from my database in my MVC5 App.

When I try to add `[DispalyName]` to some properties it works fine, but after some time app refreshes this class by itself and removes all my custom code

```
public partial class Patient
    {
        public Patient()
        {
            this.PatientDetails = new HashSet<PatientDetail>();
        }

        public int PatientID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PatientDetail> PatientDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

Why MVC does it and how to disable that?

Comment: Are you generating your classes from the database (aka Database first)?

Comment: I'm by no means an expert on this scenario but you should probably not change your DB models that are auto generated.

Comment: You shouldn't tie your MVC layer to your DB layer. Make a layer in between and map the two models together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe since you're using Database first, the entities will get completely re-created every time you refresh, thus you lose your custom attributes.

Also, to go off of Joe's comment, you should make a view model and put your `[Display]` attributes there and not directly on the entity.